# How to build typescript version of CKEditor5 custom build?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, ckeditor5

I am trying to build a custom version of CKEditor5.

Following the steps mentioned in [the official document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html) i get ckeditor.js. I wish to generate a typescript file (ckeditor.ts or ckeditor.d.ts), so that I can use it in Angular project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS files in the TS project too. You only need to set `allowJs: true` in the `tsconfig.json` file. If you have the strict mode set to `true`, then you probably need to add a simple declaration file for your builds - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/blob/master/src/typings.d.ts.

There's actually a pending ticket about generating declaration files - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/504. And the very simple declaration file for CKEditor 5 builds is presented here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/blob/46799e389bae907613774a893166646425d36de1/src/ckeditor/ckeditor.ts#L8